# Using cbind for explanatory variables in glmer in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme

I am trying to create a model in R where I want to estimate the variance of a particular ratio (in this example, nC:nT) of an individual that can be explained by the ratio of these values of its parents. In the model, I am using cbind for both the dependent and independent variables. The current generalised linear mixed effect model looks similar to this:

```
glmer(cbind(nC_offspring,nT_offspring) ~ cbind(nC_mother, nT_mother) + cbind(nC_father, nT_father) + (1|variable1) + (1|variable2), family = binomial)
```

The problem I am running into is that the results of the model of the cbind fixed effects, such as the estimates and p-values, are split up between nC and nT. i.e. I am getting estimates of nC_mother, nT_mother, nC_father and nT_father separately. In an ideal situation, I want the cbind ratio to be treated as a single factor, giving me the estimates of the cbind of the mother and of the father. I have been browsing around and cannot find a way to change the data so that the output of the glmer gives me these desired estimates. Does anybody have an idea how I can work around this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just use the ratios (instead of bind), as model you can use lm, Beta, or any other model for continuous proportions.

Comment: What are these variables?  What do they mean?  What kind of values do they have?

Comment: I am working with DNA methylation data, where the 'nC' is the number of methylated cytosines and 'nT' is the number of unmethylated cytosines. So having 9 C and 1 T means a methylation percentage of 90%, but this is of course very different from having 90C and 10T in terms of power and certainty. That's why the ratio is important to include rather than the percentage, and I would prefer running this model with cbind! But if it's not possible, I'll have to just use the 90% as an explanatory variable